# Need little explanation about GC

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have classes that described below. Does GC collect field1 and field2 from object "a" in class "C" ?

```
public abstract class A
{
//some methods and properties
}

public class B : A
{
 public int field1 { get; set; }
 public int field2 { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
 public A a { get; set; }
 private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
 public C()
 {
    a = (A)typeof(B).GetConstructor(bla, bla, bla).Invoke(bla, bla);
    ((B)a).field1 = 25;
    timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Interval = 10000;
    timer.OnTick += (o, e) => { Console.WriteLine(((B)a).field1); }; 
 }
}
```

Comment: -1 for one the worst title I've ever seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `a` is in scope, `field1` and `field2` will remain in scope.  As long as the `Timer` continues to run and reference `a`, or a reference to your instance of `C` exists, `a` will remain in scope.

I think what you're asking is if they'll be lost because we only statically know of the instance of `A` as an instance of `A`, not as an instance of `B`.  The answer to that is no, the info remains in scope.

Comment: Nitpicking: Objects don't have scopes. References have scopes, and objects have reachability, but that's a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Since `field1` and `field2` are both value types, they don't have their own locations on the stack/heap, they are inside of and a part of the memory of the instance of `B`.  This means that when that class is garbage collected, as a part of cleaning that single instance up, field1 and field2 will "go away".

Conversely, as long as the instance of 'B' sticks around, `field` and `field2` will stick around because there is no way of garbage collecting them without deleting the entire instance of `B` that owns them.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector only delete objects that are not referred to by fields in any reachable object; that's the very definition of "garbage". Your objects won't disappear as long as they're being used by any code that could possibly find them; they're only deleted when no such code is running.